# Clang tooling - Parse comma separated options

Tags: c++, clang

I am writing a source-to-source transformer as a clang tool and I am looking to have an command line option that supports comma separated values for instance `./mytool -myoptions="a,b,c"`.

The way I am creating the command line option is as follows:

```cpp
// Command Line Option Category
static llvm::cl::OptionCategory 
MyCategory("MyTool Options");


enum MyEnum {
    a, b, c
};

// Options list
llvm::cl::list<MyEnum> MyOptions("myoptions",
    llvm::cl::desc("(Required) Description"),
    llvm::cl::values(
        clEnumVal(a, "a"),
        clEnumVal(b, "b"),
        clEnumVal(c, "c")
    ),
    llvm::cl::cat(MyCategory),
    llvm::cl::ValueRequired,
    llvm::cl::OneOrMore,
    llvm::cl::CommaSeparated
);
```

I am looking for a way to parse the options in a visitor `VisitIfStmt(IfStmt *ifstmt)` where I could insert comments `// a`, `// b` and `// c` with a rewriter depending on the options selected (so `// a` if only option `a` is selected, `// ab` if options `a` and `b` are selected and so on).

My visitor should look like this:

```
bool VisitIfStmt(IfStmt *ifStmt){
    string comment_to_insert = "// ";
    
    // check if option is a
    if(/*option is a*/){
        comment_to_insert += "a";
    }

    if(/*option is b*/){
        comment_to_insert += "b";
    }
    
    if(/*option is c*/){
        comment_to_insert += "c";
    }
    
    comment_to_insert += "\n";
    rewriter.InsertTextBefore(ifStmt->getBeginLoc(), comment_to_insert);
    
    return true;
}
```

Is there a way to check if a certain option is selected from the list of comma-separated options?

Answer (score 1):

The Options List `MyOptions` is a list that has the indexes of the selected options corresponding to their position in the enum. For instance if I select options `a` and `b` with `./mytool -myoptions="a,b"` then `MyOptions` list would be `{0, 1}`.

It's possible to parse this by looping over the list and using a switch statement:

```cpp
for(unsigned int i = 0; i != MyOptions.size(); i++){
    switch(MyOptions[i]){
        case 0:
            comment_to_insert += "a"; 
            break;
        case 1:
            comment_to_insert += "b";
            break;
        case 2:
            comment_to_insert += "c";
            break;
    }
}
```